# quote the unquoted variables in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, busybox

We started using [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) to check our scripts for errors/warnings,

Now common warning what we see in all our scripts is unquoted variables.
 is there any script to correct those simple warnings/errors ?
I have below command which I use to change `$VAR` to `${VAR}`

`sed -i -r 's:\$([_a-zA-Z?][_a-zA-Z0-9]*):${\1}:g' <scriptname>`

I modified it as follows,
`sed -i -r 's:\$([_a-zA-Z?][_a-zA-Z0-9]*):"${\1}":g' <scriptname>`

above command works fine when variables are unquoted but when they are quoted e.g. `"$VAR"` it changes to `""${VAR}""`

any suggestion to whether continue doing it with `sed` or better write script to do it ?

any particular suggestions?

Comment: Check if there are already quotes.  `'s/"*yadda"*/"yadda"/'`

Comment: Quoting variables is a basic, useful thing to remember. If you forget about it and just rely on a little script doing it, you are approaching a risk: risk of the script failing and you thinking other things may be wrong, risk of forgetting about this principle of quoting variables and not taking into account. This is like making a script to fasten your belt: I think it is better to remember doing it when you sit down in the airplane.

Comment: @fedorqui problem is when we started working we were all new and over the period we improved but now we have many scripts which we have to modify we would review them but changing each line is kind of boring so thought of using script to do that.

Comment: I have a script loosely equivalent to yours, but it doesn't attempt to add double quotes because there isn't an easy way to ensure that it is handled correctly.  If you use `vim` (or `vi`), you can relatively easily create an abrreviation that will add double quotes when necessary (after you've already run your `$a` to `${a}` converter.  For example: `:map v /${[^}]*}/^V^Mi"^VESCll%a"^VESC` (where ^V, ^M are control-V and control-M, and ESC is the escape key).  Or you may prefer to keep the search separate from the replace operation — that has its merits.

Answer (score 2):

Edit carefully.
When you write `echo "This is example ${var} in the middle of the line"` you do not want to put quotes around `${var}`.
You should put all variables (except PATH, PWD and some other system vars) in lowercase.
You might want to add some mappings in `.vimrc`, that will execute your sed first or second commandline using F4 of F5 (something like `. ! ~/bin/make_my_var`) making the editing easier. In `make_my_var` you can add logic for lowercasing the vars when they are not one of a list of exceptions.
And (edited):
You might want some more standards, perhaps use a [styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml).